# Finding the limit $\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+3x}-7}{7-3x}$ as $ x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: limits

Find the limit of $$\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+3x}-7}{7-3x}$$ as $x\to\infty$.

The answer is -2/3 but I can't seem to figure out how, can someone show the steps they took to arrive at this solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+3x} - 7}{7-3x}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4+\dfrac{3}{x}}-\dfrac{7}{x}}{\dfrac{7}{x}-3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Non-rigourous intuitive solution:

As $x$ gets large, in comparison to the larger terms, the smaller terms become irrelevant. So we can think of the limit as being of order

$\frac{(4x^2)^{½}}{-3x} = -⅔$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{{\sqrt{4x^2 +3x}-7}}{7-3x} \\=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{{\sqrt{4x^2 +3x}}}{-3x} \\=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{{x\sqrt{4 +\frac{3}{x}}}}{-3x} \\=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{{\sqrt{4 +\frac{3}{x}}}}{-3} \\=-\frac{2}{3}$$

The first simplification is permissible because as $x$ is very large, the $x$ dependent terms dominate over the constants in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: It is better to show directly which terms are dominant and which ones are irrelevant in the manner shown by Rene Schipperus. It is precisely such simplification (as done in your answer) that leads to utter confusion in the minds of the students. One should avoid such oversimplification when dealing with homework problems.

Comment: In fact I would prefer the short answer by Mathmo123 where it is mentioned very clearly that it is a "non-rigorous intuitive solution" whereas in your case it looks rigorous but it is not.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Identifying dominant term(s) in finding the limits (at infinity) of rational expressions of polynomials is an often-used and accepted technique - so much so that it's termed a "rule" by many sources. Granted that it basically derives from the more explicit solution that Rene gave. But it is possible, with experience, to very quickly "spot" and simply write down limits using the coefficients of the leading term. I firmly believe that developing mathematical intuition is very important. To this end, I was merely presenting a perfectly acceptable alternative solution.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh (cont'd) I agree that Rene's solution is the best one, but that doesn't mean that mine is unacceptable. I never explicitly claimed absolute rigour, but neither is my solution mathematically unsound. If more rigour is required, Rene has already presented an excellent exposition. And I think you're vastly exaggerating the case by using hyperbole like "utter confusion". The original poster has not expressed any confusion, and he is welcome to clarify if he has any doubts.